# Xamarin Forms Sqlite Android 7+ Support

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been using the sqlite-net-pcl plugin for some, but the play store now requires an app to target Android version 7 at a minimum.

When I target this (Target Android Versions - 7.1), the application cannot open/create the database it only works for the lower version of Android, such as 5.
I'm aware that there were security changes that may have caused this but I've no idea how to address it.

I get a datapath for android like so `Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, filename);`

Then when starting my app tries to open the database connection like so

`string dbPath = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("myDbName.db3");
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);`

I want to use the `SQLiteAsyncConnection` as that handles the table locks.

The exception is:

Unhandled Exception:

`SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not open database file: /storage/emulated/0/myDbName.db3 (CannotOpen)`

I've also ensured I have read and write ticked for external storage permission.
The plugin I am using is https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net which is what xamarin forms recommend in their documentation.

Comment: All is working fine from my side after updating to android 8 has target version. Is your sqllite nuget package up to date ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is save the database file to an external storage location. You'll need to grant the app permissions to write to external storage (AppManifest -> Read/Write External Storage). Once you've done that, you can enable the permissions in the device settings (Apps->[app name]->Permissions) for testing purposes, or you can use [the Permissions Plugin by James Montemagno](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to enable Read/Write to storage. The permissions will have to be granted **before** accessing the database file.

I too am using the same plugin. I have set up the database initialisation (**after requesting storage permissions**) as follows:

```
/* Request storage permissions first!! */

// After granting storage permissions...
string dbPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string databaseFileName = "MyDatabase.db";
string fullDatabasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dbPath, databaseFileName);
_connection = new SQLiteConnection(fullDatabasePath);
```

I have not tried using `SQLiteAsyncConnection`, but it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks Tom, yes you are right. I was not actively asking the user for their permission first! I've started with some android code to ask for the permission, but didn't there was a plugin. The plugin also seems seems to be `await`able? (waits for the user to grant or reject the request?)

Comment: @user3737964 Yes, the permissions requests are `await`able, as the code must wait for the user to grant/reject the permissions. You can find an example implementation here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#in-action. You just have to put the permissions you need (in your case, "Storage"). Remember to check that permission has been granted before trying to access any files/folders!

Answer (score 0):

I think a sqlite database file is not something the user has to see and have access to it. So don't store it on a local folder.

As I said already on a similar [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/9oo1ur/how_to_check_if_app_has_storage_access_at_startup/e7vri83/).. You can skip all the permissions drama if you store the DB in a personal folder of the application. Then you don't have to ask for permissions. Check [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=vswin), which explains permissions on different android version and especially [the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c53M.png) at the end.